# macro to transpose a table into column

Tags: excel, vba

i have numbers are arrange in table like in first row 1 to 10 then in next row 11 to 20 then 21 to 30 and so on
i want that each row should transpose into single column like in any column 1 to 10 then below 10, 11 to 20, then 21 to 30 and so on

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code to a new module in the VBA editor ...

```
Public Sub TransformDataToColumns()
    Dim rngCells As Range, objCell As Range, lngWriteRow As Long
    Dim objDestSheet As Worksheet

    Set rngCells = Selection
    Set objDestSheet = Sheets("Transformed")

    objDestSheet.Cells.Clear

    For Each objCell In rngCells
        lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1
        objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 1) = objCell.Value
    Next

    objDestSheet.Activate
End Sub
```

... add a new worksheet into your workbook called **Transformed**

Now select your table of data (as shown below) and run the macro.  All things held constant, it should work for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim r1          As Range
Dim r2          As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set r1 = .Range("A1:D" & .Columns("A:D").Find("*", [A1], , , 1, 2).Row)
    Set r2 = .Range("K1")
    MultipleColumnsIntoOne r1, r2
End With
End Sub

Sub MultipleColumnsIntoOne(rSource As Range, rDest As Range)
Dim a           As Variant
Dim b           As Variant
Dim i           As Long
Dim j           As Long
Dim k           As Long

a = rSource.Value
ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1) * rSource.Columns.Count)

For j = LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2)
    For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(a(i, j)) Then
            k = k + 1
            b(k) = a(i, j)
        End If
    Next i
Next j

rDest.Resize(k).Value = Application.Transpose(b)
End Sub
```